# Effect Glass in Delphi not work

Tags: delphi

I'm testing this code Windows 7 32 and 64 bit, but still, it does not work the glass effect in any case, not return any errors, just does not work me.

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,System.SysUtils,DH_Form_Effects;

type
  DWM_BLURBEHIND = record
    dwFlags                 : DWORD;
    fEnable                 : BOOL;
    hRgnBlur                : HRGN;
    fTransitionOnMaximized  : BOOL;
  end;

function DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd : HWND; const pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND) : HRESULT; stdcall; external  'dwmapi.dll' name 'DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow';//function to enable the glass effect
function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetConsoleWindow'; //get the handle of the console window

function DWM_EnableBlurBehind(hwnd : HWND; AEnable: Boolean; hRgnBlur : HRGN = 0; ATransitionOnMaximized: Boolean = False; AFlags: Cardinal = 1): HRESULT;
var
  pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND;
begin
  pBlurBehind.dwFlags:=AFlags;
  pBlurBehind.fEnable:=AEnable;
  pBlurBehind.hRgnBlur:=hRgnBlur;
  pBlurBehind.fTransitionOnMaximized:=ATransitionOnMaximized;
  Result:=DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, pBlurBehind);
end;

begin
  try
    DWM_EnableBlurBehind(GetConsoleWindow(), True);
    Writeln('See my glass effect');
    Writeln('Go Delphi Go');
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Does this have any requirement to run? What is the problem ?

Comment: How do you know what no errors returned?

Comment: becouse compile good and not show any error in the debugger , the program running good with any error , and show the normal console , not the console with glass

Comment: I try with Window 7 32 bits and later with Window 7 64 bits , and did not work in any sistem

Comment: You are not checking the result to the call to `DWM_EnableBlurBehind`.

Comment: Glass has been removed in Windows 8. And yeah, ignoring return values isn't great. Why would you do that? We say this many many times every day here.

Comment: I was hinting you what it is your responsibility to check for any errors while working with `[winapi]` before asking us to debug a code snippet you found somewhere.

Comment: @Nemo The docs say this: *Return value

If this function succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.*

Comment: *because compile good and not show any error* does NOT mean your function calls are working. Always check API return values.  **Always**. Every single time.

Comment: *because compile good and not show any error* does NOT mean your function calls are working. Always check API return values.  **Always**. Every single time. *because it compile good* does not mean you're using it correctly, and you don't know whether it *show any error* or not because you don't check.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (on Windows 10):

[image]

I would suggest checking for any errors, rather than ignoring them:

```
hr: HRESULT;

hr := DWM_EnableBlurBehind(GetConsoleWindow(), True);
OleCheck(hr);
```

Equivalently, you can avoid the need to check return values by using `safecall` calling convention (where the compiler will insert code to check the HRESULT and throw an exception if the function failed):

```
procedure DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd: HWND; const pBlurBehind: DWM_BLURBEHIND); safecall; external  'dwmapi.dll' name 'DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow';//function to enable the glass effect


procedure DWM_EnableBlurBehind(hwnd : HWND; AEnable: Boolean; hRgnBlur : HRGN = 0; ATransitionOnMaximized: Boolean = False; AFlags: Cardinal = 1);
var
  pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND;
begin
  pBlurBehind.dwFlags:=AFlags;
  pBlurBehind.fEnable:=AEnable;
  pBlurBehind.hRgnBlur:=hRgnBlur;
  pBlurBehind.fTransitionOnMaximized:=ATransitionOnMaximized;

  DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, pBlurBehind);
end;
```

Now, since you weren't checking errors anyway - you will now know the problem. On Windows 7 with desktop composition disabled, DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow returns:

```
0x80263001 
{Desktop composition is disabled}
The operation could not be completed because desktop composition is disabled
```

Comment: Yes ! , it is the problem , how enable composition desktop ?

Comment: See [Enable and Control DWM Composition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538.aspx) and [`DwmEnableComposition()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969510.aspx).

Comment: @NemoBlack Composition is enabled by default. Presumably you disabled it.